# Визуальные состояния ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Как сделать, чтобы `ListBox` в зависимости от размеров окна мог решать во сколько строк ему выводить информацию?

Допусти есть вот такой `xaml`:

```
<ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" Rows="2"></UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Если высота окна `500px` то чтобы `UniformGrid` выводился в `2` строки, а если больше `700px` то в `3`. Как такое реализовать?

**P.S.** Что-то слышал о `VisualState` и мне кажется что их можно было б применить в данной ситуации, но нормального примера не нашел.

Comment: Через code-behind?

Comment: @VladD, А в `xaml` нельзя?

Comment: Давайте попробую, момент. Триггер должен покатить, по идее.

Comment: Окей, вопрос. Какое должно быть значение Rows, если высота окна меньше 500? Если от 500 до 700? У вас в вопросе только для ровно 500 и больше 700.

Comment: @VladD, Я это просто для примера написал, мне главное идею реализации понять. Допустим до 500  будет 1, от 500 до 700 будет 2, а больше 700  будет 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совсем без code behind, наверное, не выйдет.

Простое решение — высчитывать логику преобразования высоты окна в количество строк через конвертер:

```
class WindowHeightToRowsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var height = (double)value;
        if (height < 500.0)
            return 1;
        else if (height < 700)
            return 2;
        else
            return 3;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

С этим вы можете сделать простую привязку:

```
<Window x:Class="..." ...
        Width="525" Name="Root">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:WindowHeightToRowsConverter x:Key="H2R"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="...">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid
                        IsItemsHost="True"
                        Rows="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Root,
                                 Converter={StaticResource H2R}}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Недостаток этого решения в том, что логика класса `WindowHeightToRowsConverter` очень специфическая, и его сложно повторно использовать. Более сложное, но потенциально повторно используемое решение, например, такое.

Кладём сравнивающие конвертеры:

```
class LessThanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value < (double)parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class GreaterOrEqConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value >= (double)parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Теперь ещё для удобства указания констант в коде вот такую штуку:

```
public class DoubleExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public DoubleExtension(double value) { Value = value; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider sp) { return Value; }
}
```

Пишем следующий XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="..."
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="..."
        ...
        Name="Root">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:LessThanConverter x:Key="LT"/>
        <local:GreaterOrEqConverter x:Key="GE"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

```
<UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True">
    <UniformGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="UniformGrid">
            <Setter Property="Rows" Value="1"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <!-- если высота >= 500... -->
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Root,
                                               Converter={StaticResource GE},
                                               ConverterParameter={local:Double 500}}"
                                   Value="True"/>
                        <!-- и < 700... -->
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Root,
                                               Converter={StaticResource LT},
                                               ConverterParameter={local:Double 700}}"
                                   Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <!-- то Rows = 2 -->
                    <Setter Property="Rows" Value="2"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <!-- если высота >= 700... -->
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Root,
                                               Converter={StaticResource GE},
                                               ConverterParameter={local:Double 700}}"
                                   Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <!-- то Rows = 3 -->
                    <Setter Property="Rows" Value="3"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UniformGrid.Style>
</UniformGrid>
```

Таким образом можно комбинировать простые условия в сложные.

(`local:Double` работает благодаря `DoubleExtension`.)

Comment: Сразу несколько новых вещей увидел : `MarkupExtension` и `Condition `. 

Все работает, большое спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста! Рад, что пригодилось!